# Kendo UI Grid with form in popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to implement individual form for ajax call. I want to have a command, which opens new popup window with one field, user fills this field and then clicks "Send" and then I do an ajax call to controller. My code:

```
                   $(document).ready(function () {
                        var grid = $("#memberList-grid").kendoGrid({
                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "json",
                                    transport: {
                                        read: {
                                            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MemberSearchList", "RandomPoolSelection"))",
                                            type: "POST",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            data: function () {
                                                var data = {
                                                    SearchMember: $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.SearchMember)').val(),
                                                    SelectionId: $('#SelectionId').val()
                                                };
                                                addAntiForgeryToken(data);
                                                return data;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    schema: {
                                        data: "Data",
                                        total: "Total",
                                        errors: "Errors"
                                    },
                                    error: function (e) {
                                        display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                        // Cancel the changes
                                        this.cancelChanges();
                                    },
                                    pageSize: @(Model.PageSize),
                                    serverPaging: true,
                                    serverFiltering: true,
                                    serverSorting: true
                                },
                                pageable: {
                                    refresh: true,
                                    pageSizes: [@(Model.AvailablePageSizes)],
                                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_GridPagerMessages")
                                },
                                scrollable: false,
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        field: "PrimaryID",
                                        title: "@T("PoolMemberList.Fields.PrimaryID")",
                                        width: 150
                                    },
                                    {
                                        field: "FirstName",
                                        title: "@T("PoolMemberList.Fields.FirstName")",
                                        width: 150
                                    },
                                    {
                                        command:
                                        {
                                            text: "Exclude",
                                            click: showExclude
                                        },
                                        title: " ",
                                        width: 100
                                    }
                                ]
                            });

                        wndExclude = $("#exclude")
                            .kendoWindow({
                                title: "Excuse Reason",
                                modal: true,
                                visible: false,
                                resizable: false,
                                width: 300
                            }).data("kendoWindow");

                        excludeTemplate = kendo.template($("#excludeTemplate").html());

                    });

                    function showExclude(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                        wndExclude.content(excludeTemplate(dataItem));
                        wndExclude.center().open();
                    }
```

and template :

```
                <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="excludeTemplate">
                    <div id="exclude-container">
                        <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" id="note">
                        <br />

                    </div>
                </script>
```

how to implement sending this data (with ID) to controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do what you want is using a `partial view`.

this is your `command grid`

```
{
  command:
  {
       text: "Exclude",
       click: showExclude
  },
  title: " ",
  width: 100
}
```

and here your function :

```js
function showExclude(e) {   
  $(document.body).append('<div id="excludeWindow" class="k-rtl"></div>');
  var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
  $('#excludeWindow').kendoWindow({
        width: "80%",
        title: 'excludeForm',
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        content: "/YourController/GetPartial?id=" + dataItem.Id,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ],
        refresh: function () {
            $("#excludeWindow").data('kendoWindow').center();
        },
        close: function() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#excludeWindow').kendoWindow('destroy');
            }, 200);
        }
    }).data('kendoWindow');
}
```

After clicking on the button, you load your window(popup) and call an action that loads a `partial view` to fill the `content` of the `window`.

You can pass whatever you want to your `partial view` (for example, here I just send `Id`)

```cs
public ActionResult GetPartial(Guid id)
{
    var viewModel= new ViewModelExclude
    {
        Id = id,
    };
    return PartialView("_exclude", viewModel);
}
```

and the `partial view` is something like this:

```cs
@model ViewModelExclude
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Your action", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SendForm"}))
{
   <input class="k-rtl" name="@nameof(Model.Id)" value="@Model.Id">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
}
```

and then call Your ajax after clicking on `send` button:

```js
$("#SendForm").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var form = $(this);
     var formData = new FormData(this);
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("send", "yourController"),
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
     });
 });
```

Your `send` action something like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(ViewModelExclude view)     
{
   ....
   return Json();
}
```

Comment: variable `e` of `showExclude` function does not have `dataItem` property at all

Comment: You can get your `dataItem` in `showExclude` function, like this  : `var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));`

Comment: thank you very much! But If popup window is closed it can't be opened again :(

Comment: use this code for `close` function : `setTimeout(function () {
                $('#excludeWindow').data("kendoWindow").close();
            }, 200); ` use `close` method instead of `destroy`

Comment: it open and close popup in loop :)

Comment: please remove the `close` function and then test it. The kendo window automatically closes it . because of  `Close actions` I think. I tried and it was okay.

Comment: then window can't be opened again

Comment: even:                               `close: function () {
                                    $("#memberList-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                                }` could not help

Comment: I think no. we must close the window and that has nothing to do with the grid. I updated my answer. Please check it. Try to add `$(document.body).append('<div id="excludeWindow" class="k-rtl"></div>');` in your function when you create the window.and use the `destroy` method.  I think it can't be open again because it just loads for the first time and when you destroy, there isn't an object to open again, so appending the div every time it wants to open solves it. Please try and tell me the result.

Comment: also, not necessary to split `showExclude` function to 2

Comment: yes, I just put it for more clarity. I will update it thanks.